# Мониторинг docker при помощи контейнера zabbix агента

Tags: docker, zabbix

Есть виртуальная машина на ubuntu 22.04 с docker compose. На ней поднято несколько контейнеров. На ней я запустил контейнер с zabbix агентом 2 версии, он успешно отправляет метрики по состоянию хоста на сервер (стандартный шаблон Linux by Zabbix agent). Что же касается информации о docker (стандартный шаблон Docker by Zabbix agent 2), то данных нет совсем.

Я пробовал запустить контейнер агента в привилегированном режиме и дать доступ к docker.sock, рерультат тот же.

```
    privileged: true
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

В чем может быть причина?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно было указать, чтобы контейнер запускался от рута:

```
user: root     
privileged: true
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: Абажди. а почему нельзя натравить на заббикс хостовый докер сокет? Тогда все контейнеры будут винды. Или я что-то не так понял?